# operation getting slower of fetching data from database and showing them into auto-complete text-box using textBox_TextChanged event

Tags: c#, database, autocomplete, textbox, sql-server-ce

I am developing a winform app.I have a textbox.In this text box a user can write something into it.My job is to match every letter and comparing the text with database and show a suggestion of 10 words similar of the text from database.What i did was that:

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string a = textBox1.Text;

        // Autocomplete for textbox
        AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Database\ghfghfgh.sdf;Password=1020;");
        con.Open();

        SqlCeCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        int fetchAmount = 10;
        string userInput = textBox1.Text;
        cmnd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT top ({0}) english FROM dic WHERE english like '{1}%'",
            fetchAmount.ToString(), userInput);

        SqlCeDataReader dReader=null;
        dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dReader !=null)
        {
            while (dReader.Read())
                namesCollection.Add(dReader["english"].ToString());

        }
        else
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
        }
        dReader.Close();

        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
        // end of autocomplete

        con.Close();
    }
```

But it is getting too slower.Sometimes it crashes.I need a solution .What can i do to make it faster????

Comment: can you show me the design source of autocompete control

Comment: Sorry i cant understand your question.Can you make me clear what you want to know???@Anuj

Comment: what control have you used for autocomplete?autocomplete extender?

Answer (score 0):

Open the connection on Form level rather than on the event handler.

For ultimate performance, bypass the Query processor

```
private SqlCeConnection conn;

Form__Load()
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: Use SqlCeDataReader.Seek - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.seek(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: how can i open the connection on form level??could you clarify that??@ErikEJ

Answer (score 0):

> > What can i do to make it faster and efficient????

Hard to do with your current design. However, I think it is common to use Timer (System.Windows.Forms.Timer).

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerText.Stop();
    timerText.Start();
}

private void TimerText_Ticket(object sender, EventArgs e) // forget what event args type is it
{
    //do the operation
    timerText.Stop();
}
```

This way, you won't do query each time you make text change, but instead spend a brief period of time before the execution.

Comment: There may be, but I'm not a fan of using non-entity objects. And I imagine it will be very slow to load the entire context into a single `DataTable`/`TableView`. Imagine a whole google database to be keep in a single server memory / `TableView`